# How to select Distinct record and count total with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, distinct

Please help me to how to select and count total distinct value from table using where clause.

my code is here ..........

```
<? 

 $loc=mysql_query($che);
   while($loc288=mysql_fetch_array($loc)){

    $loc6=mysql_query("select distinct `location_name`, count(`location_name`) as CountOf from tb_job_location group by location_name");
    $loc5=mysql_fetch_array($loc6);

?>
This Query fetch result as

Delhi 1
Delhi 1
```

But it should be result like

Delhi 2

Thanks for help

Comment: `select location_name,count(*) as CountOf from tb_job_location group by location_name`

Comment: Always show `Delhi 1` because you are used `distinct`

Answer (score 0):

you are using distinct and group by in same time .

Try this

```
   $loc6=mysql_query("select `location_name`, count(*) as CountOf 
                      from tb_job_location group by location_name ");
```

Answer (score 0):

**GROUP BY** will return DISTINCT records so no need to write **DISTINCT** keyword.

Try this:

```
SELECT `location_name`, COUNT(`location_name`) AS CountOfLocations 
FROM tb_job_location 
GROUP BY location_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` caluse will group on `location_name` that will returns number of `location_name` In that case you do not required `DISTINCT` clause.

```
SELECT `location_name`,
       count(`location_name`) AS CountOf
FROM tb_job_location
GROUP BY location_name
```

Comment: Code only answers, which may well be a workable solution, are usually improved by some explanation. Please consider commenting or explaining how your suggested code works.